# How can I get a mixed hash of has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The User table has_many posts, seeds & areas.

I'm trying to get these all in the same array so I can loop through them ordered by the date they were created.

I have seen .reflect_on_association which appears to do this.. however I have more has_many associations which I don't want to be in the array.

Any thoughts on the best way to do this? I'm trying to avoid getting them all separately like:

```
posts = user.posts
seeds = user.seeds
areas = user.areas

Hash... posts, seeds, areas
```

Can I do something like:

```
posts_seeds_areas = user.reflect_on_association(:has_many, {Post, Seed, Area})
```

Is what I'm suggesting possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reflect_on_association` is for inspecting the class, not for use on instances.

To achieve what you want i'd do this

```
posts_seeds_areas = (users.posts+users.seeds+users.areas).sort_by(&:created_at)
```